# Is it possible to access sleep-tracking on watchOS real-time?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, healthkit

watchOS have sleep tracking functionality since version 7 I believe. But is it possible for a third-party watchOS app access this real-time? Is it possible to implement smart alarm based on this data?